# Allow golang through Windows firewall for testing purposes

Tags: tcp, go, network-programming

I'm trying to test some go code that starts a simple TCP server and makes a connection using

```
net.Listen("tcp", "localhost:8686")
```

I've tried creating rules in the Firewall application to allow all connections, both inbound and outbound, via TCP, but my tests still fail and I'm being prompted to allow it through the firewall each time it runs.

Answer (score 2):

I actually just fixed this. Apparently I needed to open the UDP ports as well.